# Ordering records by rand() in sql that has multiple union of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making multiple unions on the same tables
however i need to order the records of the second table by rand()
keeping in mind that I DO NOT want to have duplicate records since Iam using order by rand()

Example:
news table has the following data: (test1,test2,test3)
ads table has the following data:  (ads1,ads2,ads3)
The result should be like this:
news are sorted by id
ads are sorted by rand() : which means ads2 may comes in the top of the list, and maybe ads1 comes in the top of the list and so on..

This is my sql statement:

```
        (select news.title 
            from news
                 order by news.id desc limit 6)  union 

            (select 
                advertisements.title
            from advertisements 
                order rand() limit 1,1)
        union
            (select 
                news.title,
            from news
        order by news.id desc limit 6,6)

        union 

            (select 
                advertisements.title
            from advertisements
                order by rand() limit 2,1)
```

Comment: Please explain (with data) the exact ordering that you want.

Comment: please check the updates

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, you seem to want 6 news articles followed by an advertising one, and then repeated again.  This is not what your query does, but I'm guessing that is the intention in using `union`.

I would suggest enumerating the values and then doing the sort outside:

```
select title
from ((select n.title, @rn := @rn + 1, 'n' as which, id
       from news n cross join (select @rn := 0) params
       order by n.id desc
       limit 12
      )
      union all
      (select a.title, (@rna := @rna + 1) as rn, 'a', NULL
       from advertisements a cross join (select @rna := 0) params
       order rand()
       limit 2
      )
     ) na
order by (case when which = 'n' and rn <= 6 then 1
               when which = 'a' and rn = 1 then 2
               when which = 'n' and rn <= 12 then 3
               when which = 'a' and rn = 1 then 4
          end),
         id desc;
```

Comment: regarding the intentions, yes exactly this is what i need to do